# Python - How to import libraries without modifying its path?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-import

Anyone know the easiest ways to import these libraries without modifying the libraries' import path?

Here is the folder structure

```
src/
    main.py
    app.yaml
    index.yaml
    lib/
        flask/
        werkzeug/
        simplejson/
        __init__.py
```

For example, in the main.py I added `from lib import flask` and got

```
from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
ImportError: No module named werkzeug.exceptions
```

what is the proper way to use import flask in the main.py and for other libraries as well.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

main.py:

```
import os, sys

#libdir = os.path.abspath("lib")
#sys.path.append(libdir)
import webapp2
from flask import Flask
#app = Flask(__name__)

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello world!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

app.yaml:

```
- url: /lib
  static_dir: lib
```

Comment: make sure have `__init__.py` in each directory?. Can you show us file structure also?

Comment: already have `__init__.py`. There isn't anything else besides the starting folders from google app engine.

Comment: Is it placed in each directory like `lib, flask, werhzeug, simplejson`

Comment: Nope, flask, werhzeug, simplejson are inside the lib folder.

Comment: Add the `src/lib` path to your Python path and you're good. Or move the libraries in a folder which is already on your Python path.

Comment: @doukremt adding src/lib path to the python path is what i was thinking. But don't know how it's done exactly. I tried to use import in the app.yaml. but it wouldn't work.

Comment: @SyedHabibM Adding a `__init__.py` everywhere is *not* a good idea. It can break code that relies on pickling (for example). `lib` directories *should* be added to the pythonpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really will need to add `lib` to your path, either using site.addsitedir or manipulating sys.path.  However don't do it in main.py but put all path and other global additions in appengine_config.py which is loaded before any of your code is run.

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appengineconfig

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this in main.py (it might work in a similar way inside lib/**init**.py, but I havn't tested that.

```
libdir = os.path.abspath("lib")
sys.path.append(libdir)
```